# "JSX element 'div' has no corresponding closing tag."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-rendering

I got an error message when I tried to run the code:
"JSX element 'div' has no corresponding closing tag."
I was trying to learn conditional loading message.

```
return ( 
  <div className="home">
      {isPending && <div>Loading...<div/>}
      {blogs && <Bloglist blogs={blogs} title="All blogs!"/>}
  </div>
);‚
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You've made a mistake in your html.
You wrote this:

```
 {isPending && <div>Loading...<div/>}
```

instead of this

```
 {isPending && <div>Loading...</div>}
```

Maybe there is a confusion because you use `Bloglist` as a self closing tag

If a component is called with a self closing tag, you put the `/` before the closing bracket, but if you use two tags to pass children inside your component, the two tag must always be formatted like this :

```
<tagname ...eventually some attributes>
   html content
</tagname>
```

I would add that normally you have a lot of informations when an error is thrown by the compiler (for example the file and the line when the error occured). So when you have the information about the closing tag missing for `div`, the solution is not that hard to found

Maybe next time you have a problem that you want to share here, you should first read the error and try to understand the informations you have.